# inotifywait with a fifo queue in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, inotify, gnu-coreutils, mkfifo

I wrote a small Bash script which uses inotify-tools and the inotify interface. My problem is, that one of the commands in this function can block the execution until it's finished. This way the function gets stuck.

To solve this I would like to queue up detected files (by the close event), and read the queue from another function. Does anybody have a clue how to do this in Bash?

The variables in the following are simple strings to find directories or to assign file names.

```
inotifywait -mrq -e close --format %w%f /some/dir/ | while read FILE
do
    NAME=$(echo $CAP)_"`date +"%F-%H-%M-%S"`.pcap"
    logger -i "$FILE was just closed"
    # cp "$FILE" "$DATA/$CAP/$ENV/$NAME"
    rsync -avz --stats --log-file=/root/rsync.log "$FILE" "$DATA/$CAP/$ENV/$NAME" >> /root/rsync_stats.log
    RESULT=$?
    if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] ; then
        logger -i "Success: $FILE copied to SAN $DATA/$CAP/$ENV/$NAME, code $RESULT"
    else
        logger -i "Fail:    $FILE copy failed to SAN for $DATA/$CAP/$ENV/$NAME, code $RESULT"
    fi

    rm "$FILE"
    RESULT=$?
    if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] ; then
        logger -i "Success: deletion successfull for $FILE, code $RESULT"
    else
        logger -i "Fail:    deletion failed for $FILE on SSD, code $RESULT"
    fi

    do_something()
    logger -i "$NAME was handled"
    # for stdout
    echo "`date`: Moved file" 
done
```

I am copying the files to a SAN volume which sometimes has answering time variations. That is the reason why this function can get stuck for a while. I replaced cp with Rsync because I need the throughput stats. Cp (from coreutils) apparently doesn't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

1) You could use a named pipe as a limited-size queue:

```
mkfifo pipe

your_message_source | while read MSG
do
  #collect files in a pipe 
  echo "$MSG" >> pipe
done &

while read MSG 
do
 #Do your blocking work here
done < pipe
```

This would block on `echo "$MSG" >> pipe` when the pipe's buffer gets filled (you can get the size of that buffer with `ulimit -p` (multiply by 512). This might be sufficient for some cases.

2) You could use a file as a message queue and file lock it on each operation:

```
 #Feeder part
    your_message_source | while read MSG     
       do
            (
            flock 9
            echo "$MSG" >> file_based_queue 
            ) 9> file_based_queue 
       done &

   # Worker part
   while :
   do 
    #Lock shared queue and cut'n'paste it's content to the worker's private queue
    (
      flock 9
      cp file_based_queue workers_queue
      truncate -s0 file_based_queue   
    ) 9> file_based_queue

    #process private queue
    while read MSG 
    do
     #Do your blocking work here   
    done < workers_queue 
   done
```

You're only blocking inotifywait if you're in the worker loop in the (flock ... ) 9>file_based_queue subshell and after the flock command at the same time. You could have the queues in a RAMdisk (/dev/shm) to minimize the time you spend there so that you don't miss out on FS events.

3) Or you could use some bash interface to (or execute scripts in languages that have an interface to) database-backed message-queues or to the SysV message queue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample of using a file as a FIFO queue,
has unlimited size, is persistent on system reboot and
allows multiple readers and writers.

```
#!/bin/bash

# manages a FIFO queue on a system file.
#  every message is a line of text.
#  supports multiple writers and multiple readers.
#
# Requires: bash, inotify-tools: /usr/bin/inotifywait,
# ed, util-linux: /usr/bin/flock

set -e

# Retrieves one element
# param:
#  pipe_name
# writes to stdout:
#  element_string
# returns:
#  true on succes, false on error or end of data
_pipe_pull() {
    local pipe="${1}"
    local msg pid

_pipe_pop() {
    local fd1
    ( if ! flock --timeout 1 --exclusive ${fd1}; then
        echo "Error: _pipe_pop can't get a lock." >&2
        return 1
    fi
        [ ! -s "${pipe}" ] || \
            ed -s "${pipe}" <<< $'1p\n1d\nw'
    ) {fd1}< "${pipe}"
    :
}

    msg=""
    while [ -z "${msg}" ]; do
        if [ ! -s "${pipe}" ]; then
            inotifywait -e modify "${pipe}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
            pid="${!}"
            wait "${pid}" || return 1
        fi

        msg="$(_pipe_pop)" || \
            return 1

        if [ "${msg}" = $'\x04' ]; then
            echo "_pipe_pull: end of data." >&2
            return 1
        fi
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${msg}"
    :
}

# Adds multiple elements at once
# param:
#  pipe_name elem_1 ... elem_N
# returns:
#  true on succes, false on error
_pipe_push() {
    local pipe="${1}"
    local fd1
    shift

    ( if ! flock --timeout 10 --exclusive ${fd1}; then
        echo "Error: _pipe_push can't get a lock." >&2
        return 1
    fi
        printf '%s\n' "${@}" >> "${pipe}"
    ) {fd1}< "${pipe}"
}

pipe_file_1="$(mktemp /tmp/pipe-XXXXXX.txt)"

# submit first reader process
while msg="$(_pipe_pull "${pipe_file_1}")"; do
    printf 'Reader 1:%s\n' "${msg}"
done &

# submit second reader process
while msg="$(_pipe_pull "${pipe_file_1}")"; do
    printf 'Reader 2:%s\n' "${msg}"
done &

# submit first writer process
for i in {1..10}; do
    _pipe_push "${pipe_file_1}" "Next comes ${i}" "${i}"
done &
pid1="${!}"

# submit second writer process
for i in {11..20}; do
    _pipe_push "${pipe_file_1}" "${i}" "Previous was ${i}"
done &
pid2="${!}"

# submit third writer process
for i in {21..30}; do
    _pipe_push "${pipe_file_1}" "${i}"
done &
pid3="${!}"

# waiting for the end of writer processes
wait ${pid1} ${pid2} ${pid3}

# signal end of data to two readers
_pipe_push "${pipe_file_1}" $'\x04' $'\x04'

# waiting for the end of reader processes
wait

# cleaning
rm -vf "${pipe_file_1}"
:
```